# Qt 5 new signal slot connection with more than 3 arguments using C++11

Tags: qt5

Could someone please give a very simple C++11 example of a signal-slot connection in Qt 5 using the new syntax with function pointers where the signal/slot functions take more than 3 arguments? It is my understanding that if the signal/slot functions have more than 3 arguments, compilation fails if using C++98 with an error along the lines:

/Users/xxxx/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/qobject_impl.h:82: error: excess elements in array initializer
                QtPrivate::QMetaTypeIdHelper::qt_metatype_id(), QtPrivate::QMetaTypeIdHelper::qt_metatype_id(), 0 }; return t; } };
                                                                                                                            ^

For completeness of the answer and everyones benefit, it would also be nice to see a connection of an overloaded signal to a slot with more than 3 arguments, again using C++11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Qt which has since been fixed.